# How should I connect the final sentences?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, transitions

> "Endowed with the true blessings of the world, I can only strive forward to become a more lenient, more open-minded, and more inquisitive person. But before all that, I need to perfect the art of making pizzas."

My question is how I can effectively transition between the sentences. "But before 
all that" is noted as "inappropriate colloquialism" by Grammarly. I don't intend to use an overly formal transition here, since the tone is changing to a lighthearted one. How can I accomplish this?

Also, for the first sentence, is it a good idea to use parallelism like that? Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original sentence

> But before all that, I need to perfect the art of making pizzas.

can more simply be put as

> But **first**, I need to perfect the art of making pizzas.

Your second question of

> Endowed with the true blessings of the world, I can only strive forward to become a more lenient, more open-minded, and more inquisitive person.

might be said as

> Endowed with the true blessings of the world, I strive to become a more lenient, more open-minded, and more inquisitive person.

Eventhough you maybe "***endowed with the true blessings of the world***", there are probably more than just the three qualities that you mention with which you might better yourself.